# React: Rendering the component in different way

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have **two components** which should appear in the following way:-[image]

Now the problem statement is, i have to render component B first & then component A. But component A should be displayed on left while B on right.
One can use any CSS or bootstrap to display/arrange the component.

> **Note: component A returns rectangle and component B returns  circle / ellipse.**

Comment: what is the issue, if you are facing the problem in rendering B first then A, so for that use a state variable and timeout and display the component after 2sec.

Comment: No , this is the prblm statement i have to do this in specified way

Comment: Is the question about them not rendering at the same time or the layout? If it’s the layout and you don’t want to move component A in your HTML you could always use CSS GRID

Comment: I have to render A first and then B, one can use CSS grid to arrange them

Comment: @KerryGougeon & @ MayankShukla , basically i have to display B first on left and then A on the right ,I have to render the component using react.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure css solution: you can use `display: grid;` and `order: 1;` and `order: 2;` to rearrange order.
I made a quick [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoojOq) to demonstrate.

Or if you are not allowed to use container - something as simple as this might work: just give component B negative margin-left and component A positive margin-left. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LddwYa